# Circular rdepends dependencies between Debian packages

Tags: debian, apt, debian-stretch

I was under the impression that `depends`/`rdepends` relationships between Debian packages constitute a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG).

However, I just ran into these symmetric `rdepends` dependencies between two packages:

```
apt-cache rdepends libwww-perl        # includes libsoap-lite-perl
apt-cache rdepends libsoap-lite-perl  # includes libwww-perl
```

Both packages are installed from `stretch/main`. Is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mostly a feature.

It is impossible to have an acyclic graph:

- huge number of packages, and no tools to advice about dependencies problem.
- There are really cyclic dependencies. By building a distribution from scratch, you will notice it, e.g. now *libc* requires some external programs (e.g. resolver) and such programs requires *libc*.  One way to solve it was the use of `essential` packages: these construct a core of packages, which could depends each others.
- it is handy to split library apart of programs, and binaries apart of architecture neutral files (especially if data is huge). This could make cyclic dependency: both parts should be installed together.
- Package relation changes and packages changes. So sometime some part is moved into an other package. Cyclic dependencies hide the internal move of API provider.
- etc.

Because Debian is not just a single "distribution", but many "distributions" (e.g. 'contrib' and 'non-free', but also 'security', 'backport', 'experimental' etc.) [as Packages.gz lists], additionally sometime we include also external (non-Debian) packages, requiring an acyclic dependence graph could be difficult or just it will block *apt*, and nobody want that.  So I think cyclic dependencies are still a "feature".

Note: sometime the cycles are just "optional". One of the required packages is cyclic, but not all possibilities. 'virtual packages' makes this more difficult.